# How to put html input text into an image using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image like this:

[image]

How can I insert some input fields into the image?

It should be possible that the user click into the input fields (green boxes) of the image and enter some values?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: If your image has always the same size,  there is way with absolute positioning. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `div` element with the dimensions of your image and set it's css `position` to relative. Then set the image's position as `absolute` and its coordinates 0,0. Then you can position all the checkboxes by absolute positioning as well.

By assuring that the wrapping `div` has `position: relative;`, you can position the checkboxes (and the image) from the border of the `div`.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="...">
  <input type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 100px;">
  <input type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 200px;">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;  
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `absolute` position like:

HTML:

```
<img src="imageName.png" id="img" />
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```

CSS:

```
#txt{
    position : absolute;
    left : 200px;
    top:150px;
}
#img{
    position : relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions comes to my mind:

1 - Use some container (div, table) with width and height same as image and style like so:

```
position: relative;
background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyJet.png") no-repeat;
```

Then put input fields in this container with style (use different left and top for each input)

```
position: relative;
left: 100px;
top: 5px;
```

2 - In some container with position other than static (needs for positioning child elements with positions) put that image as `img` element and all input fields with style:

```
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
```

All you need is to position them all as you wish by changing left and top properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could achieve it by using css grid.

Using CSS grid you can overlap items easily.

Here is an example using CSS grid:

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.testInput1 {
  align-self: center;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.testInput2 {
  align-self: center;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.testInput3 {
  align-self: center;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gridContainer">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/1c6/neon-blur-1-1172436.jpg" class="img" />
    <div class="testInput1">
      <input type="text" id="testInput1" value="test input 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="testInput2">
      <input type="text" id="testInput2" value="test input 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="testInput3">
      <input type="text" id="testInput3" value="test input 3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image as background to a div and add absolute positioned inputs over the div,

**HTML**

```
<div class="mydiv" >
    <input type="text" class="fistinput" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.mydiv{
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyJet.png');
    height:447px;
    width:591px;
}
.fistinput{
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    left:200px;
    width:50px;
}
```

Try [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z3trxc4x/5/)